# Whats the correct way to pipe output to more than one OutputStream?

Tags: java, groovy, outputstream

I'd like to pipe an `OutputStream` to more than one receiving `OutputStream`. Is there out-of-the-box support this, or a simpler way to implement this than my solution?

For arguments sake, say I want to pipe the output of running `ls /tmp` to `System.out` AND a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

#### My current solution:

I created a `MultiOutputStream` class, to delegate to multiple `OutputStream`'s. Is there a simpler/preferred way of achieving the same outcome?

```
class MultiOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    List<OutputStream> streams

    MultiOutputStream(List<OutputStream> streams = []) {
        this.streams = streams
    }

    @Override
    void write(int b) throws IOException {
        streams.each { it.write(b) }
    }

}
```

#### Usage in example:

```
def baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
def proc = 'ls /tmp'.execute()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(
        new MultiOutputStream([System.out, baos]),
        System.err
)
proc.waitForOrKill(5000)
println "Do something with this -> " + new String(baos.toByteArray())
```

Comment: Hmm, override some log4j stuff